Batch Normalization and the effect of scaled weights on the gradients
I have been reading the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.05350, and I am having a hard time with some claims and derivations made in the paper.
First of all, the main thing I am interested in is that Batch Normalization makes the output of the layer invariant to the scaling of the weights of the layer, but the same is not true for the gradients. In other words, due to normalization, the scale of the weights do not really matter in the forward pass, but it does not matter in the backward pass and thus affects the learning rate.
This is shown in section $3$ of the paper, but I have no clue how the authors arrive at the conclusion that the gradients do change by $1/\alpha$, i.e. they mention that
$\nabla y_{BN}(X;\alpha w, \gamma, \beta) = \nabla y_{BN}(X;w, \gamma, \beta) / \alpha$
what already really confuses me is that if we know that
$y(X,\alpha w , \gamma, \beta) = y(X, w, \gamma, \beta)$,
why does the gradient change? If both expressions are equal, why cannot we simply take the gradients with respect to the second expression $y(X, w, \gamma, \beta)$?
I would really appreciate if some one can explain me how this equivalence is derived.
